# Export output of a script to a new file

Tags: bash

I have a script that creates output using the eval command. The script is based on a config file and user input.
Is there a way to copy this output into a new file?

```
[aaron@aaron home]#./add contact
Get contact
Who's contact details do you want? Joe
{"fname":"Joe","lname":"Bloggs","number":"12345678910"}
[aaron@aaron home]#
```

Comment: Can you edit the script, or you only on the receiving end here?

Comment: I can edit the script myself

Comment: You can have that `echo` statement (or `printf` or whatever) that spits out the json, piped to a `tee` command so it will go to stdout (where you can see it) and a file at the same time. Like... `echo $output | tee myoutputfile.txt` *assuming the script is also bash like that tag.

Comment: @JNevill Actually i used the wrong syntax, thanks very much it works.